# How to create multiple channels on websocket server with NodeJS websocket?

Tags: node.js, websocket, channel

I'm using this code to handle user's request on a websocket server:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(405);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(3333, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 3333');
});
wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});
function originIsAllowed(origin) {
    // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
    return true;
}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
        // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
        request.reject();
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
        return;
    }

    var connect = request.accept('register', request.origin)
    connect.on('message', function(messageText) {
        // do business logic here if message coming into the register channel
    })

    connect.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connect.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    });
})
```

Now how can I create an other channel to handle the other types of messages?

I tried this, but get `WebSocketRequest may only be accepted or rejected one time.` error message:

```
    var connect = request.accept('register', request.origin)
    connect.on('message', function(messageText) {
        // business logic here if message coming into the register channel
    })

    var getPhotos = request.accept('get_photos', request.origin)
    getPhotos.on('message', function(messageText) {
        // business logic here if message coming into the get_photos channel
    })
```

How can I handle multiple channels? Is it possible with this `websocket` npm package?